# Move code from TFVC on TFS 2010 to TFVC on Azure DevOps Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, git-tfs

I have some projects on TFVC source control on TFS 2010. I want just to migrate the source code from TFS 2010 to TFVC on Azure DevOps Server.

I don't want to process an upgrade of the entire collection to a newest version. I Just want to transfer my code with history.

I tried Git-TFS. I cloned my repository on TFS 2010, but I don't know how I can update the remote URL for TFVC repos and push on Azure DevOps Server.

Any ideas how I can do it? Or other tools that I can use?.

In the case I decide to migrate without history how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for Git on how to add remotes?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes. But I don't want to migrate to remote Git.

Comment: Are you talking about Azure DevOps Server 2019 ?

Answer (score 1):

`git-tfs` is a two-way bridge between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS.

If you want to move code from TFVC on TFS2010 to TFVC on Azure DevOps 2019 and keep history.

You have to do the upgrade process of entire project collection.

`In the case I decide to migrate without history how can I do it`

You could just create corresponding new team projects and workspaces. Pull down your source code from your TFS2010 workspaces/projects. Copy and paste source code files/folders in new workspace.  Then check in them back to Azure DevOps Server 2019.

We advise you keep preview TFVC repository of 2010 online but read-only to view history.

Same with Azure DevOps Service, hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the last maintainer of the git-tfs tool (even if I no more work on it)

Git-tfs could be used to migrate from TFVC to git (with history and branches if your history is not too complex).

But in no way it could be used to push this history to another empty TFVC project.

So don't expect something from here.

Fun fact (not so fun for you) :

To prevent regression developing git-tfs, I created a TFVC project on Codeplex used to run smoke tests in a Continuous Integration job.

When Microsoft decided to close Codeplex, I contacted a guy working in the source control team inside Microsoft to help me migrate from Codeplex to Azure Devops (at the time called VSTS) which is the problem you try to solve.

I don't know if they put a lot of effort into this but no one was able give me a solution. The only thing they think about was to use git-tfs, that I confirm you is not able to do it!

That could give you an idea of the problem you're trying to solve...

Ps: that also show that TFVC is not an enough flexible source control and their is a much higher added value to migrate to git (like nearly everyone is doing it...)